# Failing to create relationship due to key incompatibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to create a upvote/downvote system and I am getting an error when trying to create a migration.
I am kinda new into .NET so I don't really know what would I have to do to solve my problem.

The error message that is being returned for me is:

> The relationship from 'Vote.Comment' to 'Comment.Votes' with foreign key properties {'CommentId' : string} cannot target the primary key {'PostId' : string, 'UserId' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Here is all the neccessary code

- OnModelCreating function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        
        {...}     

        #region Posts

        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasKey(p => p.UserId);
        
        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .Property(p => p.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .Property(p => p.Text)
            .HasMaxLength(1500);

        // Comments
        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.PostId, c.UserId });

        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PostId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .Property(c => c.CommentText)
            .HasMaxLength(1500);

        // Votes
        builder.Entity<Vote>()
            .HasKey(v => new { v.PostId, v.CommentId });

        builder.Entity<Vote>()
            .HasOne(v => v.User)
            .WithMany(v => v.Votes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);

        builder.Entity<Vote>()
            .HasOne(v => v.Post)
            .WithMany(v => v.Votes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.PostId);

        builder.Entity<Vote>()
            .HasOne(v => v.Comment)
            .WithMany(c => c.Votes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.CommentId);

        #endregion
    }
```

- AppUser Class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
        Follower = new List<FollowUser>();
        Following = new List<FollowUser>();

        Blocker = new List<BlockUser>();
        Blocking = new List<BlockUser>();

        Posts = new List<Post>();
        Comments = new List<Comment>();
    } 
    
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public required string FullName { get; set; }
    
    // Follow system
    public ICollection<FollowUser> Follower { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FollowUser> Following { get; set; }
    
    //Block System
    public ICollection<BlockUser> Blocker { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlockUser> Blocking { get; set; }

    // Posting System
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }

    // Account Settings
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; } = false;
}
```

- PostEntity Class

```
public abstract class PostEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

- Comment Class

```
public class Comment : PostEntity
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }

    public Comment(string userId, string postId, string commentText)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        UserId = userId;
        PostId = postId;
        CommentText = commentText;
    }
}
```

- Vote Class

```
public class Vote
{
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public readonly Post? Post;
    public readonly string? PostId;
    public readonly Comment? Comment;
    public readonly string? CommentId;
    public bool IsUpvote { get; set; }
    
    public Vote(string? postId, string? commentId)
    {
        PostId = postId;
        CommentId = commentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot to unpack in your code. Start with "builder.Entity<>.HasKey". Its supposed to inform ef about the primary-key of an entity. Right in the beginning, however, you are telling it that the Post-entities primary-key is "UserId". Looking at the Post class this is clearly not the case. I'd suggest to read-up on the topic of relations in ef again because you are clearly confusing things.

Comment: @SanchoPanza Thank you for you answer. That was literally what I was doing right now. The relationship topic is something that was overwhelming me and it still is a little.

Comment: Hints: avoid strings as primary-keys, get rid of all composite-keys (.HasKey(c => new { c.PostId, c.UserId })) in your code (I highly doubt you'll need them) and last but not least, reconsider your class inheritances (having Comment extend Post seems strange for example)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you do not need this one in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
builder.Entity<Comment>()
        .HasKey(c => new { c.PostId, c.UserId });
```

Also, I have noticed that the `Vote` class has properties with the `readonly` keyword. Try to get rid of them and create a default constructor. And I'm curious why the IDs are `string`? Consider using `GUIDs` instead.

This should be something like this:

```
public class Vote
{
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public Post? Post;
    public Guid? PostId;

    public Comment? Comment;
    public Guid? CommentId;

    public bool IsUpvote { get; set; }
    
    public Vote() {}

    public Vote(string? postId, string? commentId)
    {
        PostId = postId;
        CommentId = commentId;
    }
}
```

And I am not sure about the overloaded constructor `public Vote(string? postId, string? commentId)`. Do you really need it?

Additionally, it looks like you can remove some bindings in the `OnModelCreating` method, since they are defined in your entites by default. Try remove this, for example:

```
builder.Entity<Vote>()
            .HasOne(v => v.Comment)
            .WithMany(c => c.Votes)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.CommentId);
```